# iphone audio plays on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, audio, device

The following code plays well on the simulator but the audio doesnt play on the actual device. I have tries aif, wav and mp3 ... all three with the same behaviour.
Please sugest what could be wrong.

```
SystemSoundID aSound;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(),CFSTR("drop"), CFSTR("wav"), NULL), &aSound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(aSound);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn! I realized that for some reason, no app in my device was playing an audio! Reboot worked.

Comment: One time I ran into this and it's because I had my device on "silent" mode. *facepalm*